# How to join multiple model using select_related?

Tags: django

i have few models namely

```
class Alpha(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class XXX(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Alpha)

class YYY(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(Alpha)
```

Now while doing select_related like this

```
test = Alpha.objects.filter(id=pk).select_related('XXX')
```

It gives me `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related, choices are YYY`

I understand that YYY is at OneToOne, so its showing up - but is there a way to fetch XXX also ? or should i use "prefetch_related". But i dont wanna use prefetch as its just making slow queries and meanwhile i have 7 models which needs to be select_related :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefetch_related in order to achieve this. Also, add related_name in foreign key fields for referencing.

```
class Alpha(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class XXX(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Alpha, related_name='xxx')

class YYY(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(Alpha, related_name='yyy')

Alpha.objects.filter(id=pk).prefetch_related('xxx', 'yyy')
```

Comment: In `prefetch_related`, without related_name the model will not be able to reference other models using its pk as foreign key. But in case of `select_related` the field will already be there to reference the model. You can view the documentation for more details. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: is using prefetch_related good, or i can simply use select * on other models and make this as seprate quries ?

Comment: I suggest using prefetch_related and select_related when working with multiple tables and its a good way optimizing your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select_related` when going in the direction of the 1 model.
For example `XXX.objects.all().select_related('alpha')`

But when you go from 1 towards many you have to use `prefetch_related`.

so `Alpha.objects.all().prefetch_related('xxx')`

Check out this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/django-select-related-and-prefetch-related-f23043fd635d?gi=8c4697771c66)